# Show that a decimal with a repeating pattern represents a rational number?

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

> Exercise 1.3.1 (Guide to Analysis, Hart, p.4) Consider a decimal of the form $x=0.a_1a_2...a_n$ with a repeating pattern of $n$ digits. Write $x = 0.a_1a_2 ... a_n$. Express $10^nx$ as a decimal. Then subtract $x$ and check that $10^nx - x$ is an integer. Deduce that $x$ is rational. Now extend the method to prove that all decimals with a repeating pattern represent rational numbers.

First question:  let $x= 0.33$, then $10^2*.33 - 0.33=33-0.33=32.67$ is not an integer. Now, it seems that I miss understood something. Can someone explains to me what he is saying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $x=0.14141414...$.   Then $100x=14.141414...$, so $100x-x=14,$ so $99x=14,$ so $x=14/99$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you! this is an answer to my question. I miss that I write .33333333 for ever. I see the point! write your comment to accept it as an answer.

Comment: 1) How did you go from $x=0.25$ to $0.33$.  2) $0.25000000....$ and $0.3300000....$ terminate and the repeating terms are $0$.  If you do this *by the letter* for $0.33$ then the repeating parts are the $0$ at the third third position so you do $10^4*0.33 - 10^2*0.33 = 3300 - 33 = 2367$ *is* and integer and $x =0.33 = \frac {2367}{9900}$.

Comment: I was also wondering how you went from $0.25$ to $.33$; I took the liberty of changing $10^x-x$ to $10^nx-x$, which I think you intended;  note:  repeating decimals can also be thought of as geometric series;  @fleablood:  I think you meant $\color{red}{32}67$

Comment: it was a mistake, I corrected it. It should be something like 0.33.

Comment: If you mean $x=0.333333......$ then you have the repeating pattern of length 1 starting at position 1 so you multiply by $10^1$ so $10x = x = 3.3333..... - 0.33333... = 3$ *is* and intger and $x = \frac 3{9} = \frac 13$.

Comment: But $0.33= 0.33000000....$ is not $0.333333.....$ which repeats.

Comment: Yes, you're right. As I studied in school, we represent the repeated form by only first digits of repeated. e.g. 0.3333333 = 0.3 (we put a bar/point over 3). I miss the point that the repeated form goes to infinity and $10*0.333... - 0.333=3$.

Comment: Should note that if you had say $0.5612345123451234512345....$ then the repeaing patter in $n = 5$ long, but it doesn't start at the decimal point.  It is $k =3$ past the decimal point.  We *can* do $10^{5+3}x - 10^3x = 5612345.1234512345... - 56.1234512345 = 5612289$ and get $x=\frac{5612289}{99999000}$.  But it's just as easy to just to $10^5x -x=56123.451234512345...-0.5612345=56122.89$ and $x = \frac{56122.89}{99999}$ is rational. Even if $56122.89$ is *not* an integer.  It's a *terminating* decimal and is rational.)

Comment: "I miss the point that the repeated form goes to infinity"  Well, that *was* the entire point.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, let $x=0.14141414...$.

Then $100x=14.141414...$, so $100x-x=14,$ so $99x=14$ so $x=14/99$.

In general, if $x=0.\overline {a_1a_2\dots a_n}$, where the overline indicates it's repeated,

then $10^nx=a_1a_2...a_n.\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_n}$, so $10^nx-x=a_1a_2\dots a_n$, so $x=\dfrac{a_1a_2\dots a_n}{10^n-1} $ is rational.

Comment: This could be further generalized to show that $b_1b_2\dots b_k.c_1c_2\dots c_m\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_n}$ is rational as well